# Where are my SQL Developer preferences saved?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm looking to copy my SQL Developer preferences across to multiple devices and I'm wondering where I'd find the file/files to copy across.

When referring to preferences in particular, I'm talking about the preferences accessed through Tools -> Preferences. I would like an exact copy of all preferences saved here (down the table filters and startup script location) with the intention of applying them to other PC's.

Another preference that I would like to transfer is the filter i've applied to 'Other Users' to filter out certain Schemas. I hope this is possible.

Thanks

Comment: On Windows I think this is in `%AppData%\sqldeveloper`

Answer (score 9):

The default locations are :

Windows.... AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer

Linux/Mac..  ~/.sqldeveloper

*Note 1: the AppData folder is frequently 'hidden' in Windows by default.*

*Note 2: each version of SQL Developer gets its own directory, although certain things are shared such as reports, connections, sqlhistory*

[image: Windows APP Data folders for SQL Developer preferences]

The easiest way to 'copy' across machines is to use a dropbox/GDrive/.. type thing that will sync.

Regardless of that you can tell sqldev where to store preferences with the following setting.

```
edit sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf
   - add the path to the Dropbox or where ever location
    AddVMOption -Duser.home=/Users/klrice/Dropbox/sqldev
```

If you do this on N devices, it should all just sync and work seamless.

Ref: my blog on this from '12

http://krisrice.io/2012-05-12-sql-developer-shared-setup-from-any/

Comment: Thanks for this, I just have a couple of questions: Firstly, where do I run the edit/ AddVMOption code (SQL Plus?)? Secondly, if I point the AddVMOption line at a shared folder with an existing SQL directory on there, will SQL Developer on that machine simply use the preferences found in that folder? Lastly, can any users with access to the shared preferences folder modify the shared preferences?

Comment: 1. file to edit it :sqldeveloper/bin/sqldeveloper.conf    2. sqldev uses this user.home over anything else.    3. of course as it's just files so if someone has write access, they can edit them

Comment: tried this for sqldeveloper system19.2.1.247.2212 but it's not working. In sqldeveloper about window I can see the `user.home` and `ide.user.home` are set to my specified  location `H:\Data\Apps\sqldeveloper_profile` but sqldeveloper still uses the default %appdata/SQL Developer% folder to store all files..
edit: lookup up all other settings with appdata and added those to my `sqldeveloper.conf` file and now my settings are properly picked up. My connections are restored

Answer (score 0):

For Sql developer 18.2.0, product-preferences.xml is in C:\Documents and Settings\userid\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\system18.2.0.183.1748\o.sqldeveloper

Comment: found the XP user in 2018. Question is: whyyyyyyy